# Css responsive not working when deployed on server

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I made a responsive home design with only html and css. When I deploy it locally the responsive part works perfectly, so I sended the files to the owner of the page, but he told me that the page wasn't responsive. He deployed it locally and in fileZila but it's like there's no media queries.

This are my html head tags.

```
<head>
  <title>Alpha</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; minimumscale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

And here is some example of my css code, I'm not even using sass because for the project I can't use libraries (it's a pretty old page)

```
.navbar{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #c91111;
}

.navbar button{
  margin-right: 25px;
}
  
.navbar img{
  height: 4rem;
  width: 19rem;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

And at the end I have some responsive code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 270px) {
  .navbar button{
    width: 6rem;
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .menu_item{
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 11rem;
    height: 15rem;
  }

  .menu_item_4{
    height: 17rem;
  }

  .menu_item a{
    padding: 1rem;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .mobile-item{
    padding: 0 !important;
  }
}
```

Here is the live example https://serviciosi.online/alpha/testhome/
Now it isn't responsive on my computer when I enter that link, even though the files haven't been changed.
Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should Probably Check the file permissions and owner of the file

## EX:

[image]

Comment: Yep, it was some sort of denided permission from the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the last time I used responsive CSS was quite a while ago, I'm not sure if this would impact it, but in your `<meta>` tag in your HTML code, you switch between using semicolons and commas to separate the elements, which is generally not advisable in coding.

If this doesn't work, have you considered using percentage-based margins in order to have it automatically adjust?

Answer (score 0):

max width is 270px so it wont work on resolution greater than 270px